# Group rows by certain timeperiod dending on other factors

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

What I start with is a large dataframe (more than a million entires) of this structure:

```
id  datetime             indicator  other_values ...
1   2020-01-14 00:12:00  0          ...
1   2020-01-17 00:23:00  1          ...
  ... 
1   2021-02-01 00:00:00  0          ...
2   2020-01-15 00:05:00  0          ...
2   2020-03-10 00:07:00  0          ...
  ... 
2   2021-05-22 00:00:00  1          ...
  ...
```

There is no specific order other than a sort by `id` and then `datetime`. The dataset is not complete (there is not data for every day, but there can be multiple entires of the same day).

Now for each time where `indicator==1` I want to collect every row with the same `id` and a `datetime` that is at most 10 days before. All other rows which are not in range of the indicator can be dropped. In the best case I want it to be saved as a dataset of time series which each will be later used in a Neural network. (There can be more than one `indicator==1` case per id, `other values` should be saved).

An example for one id: I want to convert this

```
id  datetime             indicator  other_values ...
1   2020-01-14 00:12:00  0          ...
1   2020-01-17 00:23:00  1          ...
1   2020-01-17 00:13:00  0          ...
1   2020-01-20 00:05:00  0          ...
1   2020-03-10 00:07:00  0          ...
1   2020-05-19 00:00:00  0          ...
1   2020-05-20 00:00:00  1          ...
```

into this

```
id  datetime             group      other_values ...
1   2020-01-14 00:12:00  A          ...
1   2020-01-17 00:23:00  A          ...
1   2020-01-17 00:13:00  A          ...
1   2020-05-19 00:00:00  B          ...
1   2020-05-20 00:00:00  B          ...
```

or a similar way to group into group A, B, ... .

A naive python for-loop is not possible due to taking ages for a dataset like this.
There is propably a clever way to use `df.groupby('id')`, `df.groupby('id').agg(...)`, `df.sort_values(...)` or `df.apply()`, but I just do not see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this with `df.agg`, but you can put your for loop inside the groupby using `.apply()`. That way, your comparisons/lookups can be done on smaller tables, then groupby will handle the re-concatenation:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import uuid

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "datetime": [
        '2020-01-14 00:12:00',
        '2020-01-17 00:23:00',
        '2021-02-01 00:00:00',
        '2020-01-15 00:05:00',
        '2020-03-10 00:07:00',
        '2021-05-22 00:00:00',
    ],
    "indicator": [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
})
df.datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)

timedelta = datetime.timedelta(days=10)
def consolidate(grp):
    grp['Group'] = None
    for time in grp[grp.indicator == 1]['datetime']:
        grp['Group'][grp['datetime'].between(time - timedelta, time)] = uuid.uuid4()
    return grp.dropna(subset=['Group'])

df.groupby('id').apply(consolidate)
```

If there are multiple rows with `indicator == 1` in each `id` grouping, then the for loop will apply in index order (so a later group might overwrite an earlier group). If you can be certain that there is only one `indicator == 1` in each grouping, we can simplify the `consolidate` function:

```
def consolidate(grp):
    time = grp[grp.indicator == 1]['datetime'].iloc[0]
    grp = grp[grp['datetime'].between(time - timedelta, time)]
    grp['Group'] = uuid.uuid4()
    return grp
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do it with `pd.merge_asof()`. Let's create our data:

```
data = {'id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        'datetime': ['2020-01-14 00:12:00', 
                    '2020-01-17 00:23:00',
                    '2020-01-17 00:13:00',
                    '2020-01-20 00:05:00',
                    '2020-03-10 00:07:00',
                    '2020-05-19 00:00:00',
                    '2020-05-20 00:00:00'],
        'ind': [0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].astype('datetime64')
```

Data:

```
   id            datetime  ind
0   1 2020-01-14 00:12:00    0
1   1 2020-01-17 00:23:00    1
2   1 2020-01-17 00:13:00    0
3   1 2020-01-20 00:05:00    0
4   1 2020-03-10 00:07:00    0
5   1 2020-05-19 00:00:00    0
6   1 2020-05-20 00:00:00    1
```

Next, let's add a date to the dataset and pull all dates where the indicator is 1.

```
df['date'] = df['datetime'].dt.date.astype('datetime64')
df2 = df.loc[df['ind'] == 1, ['id', 'date', 'ind']].rename({'ind': 'ind2'}, axis=1)
```

Which gives us this:

df:

```
   id            datetime  ind       date
0   1 2020-01-14 00:12:00    0 2020-01-14
1   1 2020-01-17 00:23:00    1 2020-01-17
2   1 2020-01-17 00:13:00    0 2020-01-17
3   1 2020-01-20 00:05:00    0 2020-01-20
4   1 2020-03-10 00:07:00    0 2020-03-10
5   1 2020-05-19 00:00:00    0 2020-05-19
6   1 2020-05-20 00:00:00    1 2020-05-20
```

df2:

```
   id       date  ind2
1   1 2020-01-17     1
6   1 2020-05-20     1
```

Now let's join them using `pd.merge_asof()` with `direction=forward` and a tolerance of 10 days. This will join all data up to 10 days looking forward.

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df.drop('ind', axis=1), df2, by='id', on='date', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('10d'), direction='forward')
```

Which gives us this:

```
   id            datetime  ind       date  ind2
0   1 2020-01-14 00:12:00    0 2020-01-14   1.0
1   1 2020-01-17 00:23:00    1 2020-01-17   1.0
2   1 2020-01-17 00:13:00    0 2020-01-17   1.0
3   1 2020-01-20 00:05:00    0 2020-01-20   NaN
4   1 2020-03-10 00:07:00    0 2020-03-10   NaN
5   1 2020-05-19 00:00:00    0 2020-05-19   1.0
6   1 2020-05-20 00:00:00    1 2020-05-20   1.0
```

Next, let's work on creating groups. There are three rules we want to use:

1. The next value of ind2 is `NaN`
2. The next value of ID is not the current value of ID (we're at the last value in the group)
3. The next day is 10 days greater than the current

With these rules, we can create a Boolean which we can then cumulatively sum to create our groups.

```
df['group_id'] = df['ind2'].eq(  (df['ind2'].shift() == np.NaN) 
                               | (df['id'].shift() != df['id'])
                               | (df['date'] - df['date'].shift() > pd.Timedelta('10d') ) 
                              ).cumsum()

    id            datetime  ind       date  ind2  group_id
0    1 2020-01-14 00:12:00    0 2020-01-14   1.0         1
1    1 2020-01-17 00:23:00    1 2020-01-17   1.0         1
2    1 2020-01-17 00:13:00    0 2020-01-17   1.0         1
3    1 2020-01-20 00:05:00    0 2020-01-20   NaN         1
4    1 2020-03-10 00:07:00    0 2020-03-10   NaN         1
5    1 2020-05-19 00:00:00    0 2020-05-19   1.0         2
6    1 2020-05-20 00:00:00    1 2020-05-20   1.0         2
```

Now we need to drop all the `NaNs` from `ind2`, remove `date` and we're done.

```
df = df.dropna(subset='ind2').drop(['date', 'ind2'], axis=1)
```

Final output:

```
   id            datetime  ind  group_id
0   1 2020-01-14 00:12:00    0         1
1   1 2020-01-17 00:23:00    1         1
2   1 2020-01-17 00:13:00    0         1
5   1 2020-05-19 00:00:00    0         2
6   1 2020-05-20 00:00:00    1         2
```

Comment: Really neat! I've never used `merge_asof` before.

Comment: Isn't it?? I just discovered it myself answering this!

Comment: thank you :) but this does not group them and only removes the ones which are not in range or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: You are correct. I am working on that part now

Comment: Added a solution